# GUIMiner Won't Start

Tags: miner-configuration, cpu-mining, guiminer

I am trying to mine Bitcoin on my CPU in Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter. *I know about the consequences of CPU-only mining*. I have downloaded GUIMiner - title bar looks like this:

[image]

However, when I configure it *(more info below)* and hit 'Start mining!', nothing happens - bottom bar looks like this:

[image]

**My Setup**

**Miner:** *Ufasoft CPU miner*

**Other Info:**

[image]

If anyone can help get this working, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you already create an account at mining.bitcoin.cz?

Comment: @ColinDean Yep. Works fine from DiabloMiner on my machine with a GPU.

Comment: Is the path to your miner correct? Try moving it to a location other than your desktop, like c:\

Comment: try removing http:// could be that the pool no longer supports get-work protocol.

Answer (score 1):

According to mining.bitcoin.cz, getwork protocol is removed. Use the stratum protocol instead. stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333

> 08.07.2013
>   Getwork protocol support ended. Please be sure your miners support Stratum protocol. You can still use your old getwork miners with Stratum proxy installed on your mining rig.

Answer (score 0):

- go to C:\Program Files\Ufasoft\Coin
- then rename the "coin-miner.exe" to "bitcoin-miner.exe"
- then in Ext. path on GUIminer enter C:\Program Files\Ufasoft\Coin\bitcoin-miner.exe